# The right way to make select with offset (pagination) query in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, pagination, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to select data from my view with offset to make pagination and also order by registration date.

I have code sample below.

```
SELECT student_id,student_name 
FROM student 
WHERE student_id IN(
                 SELECT TOP 15 student_id 
                 FROM student(
                         SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY register_date_time DESC) AS rowNo,student_id
                         FROM student
                        ) tb_pagination WHERE rowNo > 30
                 )
```

My code runs correctly but it too slow to response from server to client request.

Can anybody tell me how to make it better?

Comment: [This article is for 2000 and 2005 versions, should work in 2008  as well.](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042606-1.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT student_id,student_name 
FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY register_date_time DESC) AS rowNo, 
        student_id, 
        student_name
        FROM student
    ) tb_pagination
WHERE rowNo > 30 
AND rowNo < 45
```